# Notifying angular of change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to make angular refresh itself as soon as the data model has changed. I have data store object is a rather complex model but in the end should provide angular with the data it has to render to screen. What I can't figure out is how to notify angular that things are different.

I guess I haven't fully understood how I should be using $scope, but I can't for the life of me get it to work properly. I'm sorry if this is a trivial problem.

```
<html ng-app="testApp">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function Store() {
                this.data = [{ msg: "a" }, { msg: "b" }];

                this.performWeirdModifications = function () {
                    data.push({ msg: "c" });
                    data.push({ msg: "d" });
                }
            }

            var store = new Store();

            angular.module('testApp', []).controller('DataController', function () {
                this.data = store.data;
            });            
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="DataController as dataCtrl">
        <button onclick="store.performWeirdModifications()">Simulate something</button>
        <div ng-repeat="data in dataCtrl.data">{{data.msg}}</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: while you can use $scope.$apply to solve the problem, what i am not getting is, why dont you use Store as a service... which is more angular way...

Comment: The problem is that the store here as actually judge pile of legacy code which does a lot of stuff. Otherwise you'd build it into angular from the start..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it to `$scope`.

```
    angular.module('testApp', []).controller('DataController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.data = store.data;
    });
```

Below is how I would have done it using service.

```
<html ng-app="testApp">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            angular.module('testApp', [])
            .service('Store', function() {
                this.data = [{ msg: "a" }, { msg: "b" }];

                this.performWeirdModifications = function () {
                    this.data.push({ msg: "c" });
                    this.data.push({ msg: "d" });
                };
                return this;
            })
            .controller('DataController', function ($scope, Store) {
                $scope.data = Store.data;
                $scope.getData = function() {
                    Store.performWeirdModifications();
                    $scope.data = Store.data;
                };
            });            
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="DataController as dataCtrl">
        <button ng-click="getData()">Simulate something</button>
        <div ng-repeat="d in data">{{d.msg}}</div>
    </body>
</html>
```